# Can one see the latest activities in "big list" questions without reading all answers again?

Tags: support, user-interface

There is a good question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics). It is a "big list" question. sometimes it appears in active list. So I want to know what activity  done there? but how?

> Can one see the latest activities in  "big list" questions without reading all answers again?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are interested in the very last activity and you have the question in front of you in the active list, click the timestamp next to the username displayed, it will take you to the latest activity

Comment: I cant see it quid

Comment: When you look here http://mathoverflow.net/?tab=active for example it will say thing like "answered 35 minutes ago by user12345" click the "answered 35 minutes" same for "modified 2 hours ago by user21345" You are taken to the last active post in the thread (except for corner cases, such as the last active post being deleted in the interim).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the *Active* tab for the list of answers, and you will see the most recent activity at top.

One issue, however, is that this tab is sticky, and so you will continue to get the "Active" answers at top as you browse to other questions. So you'll have to set it back to *Votes* or whatever for your usual view. (In my opinion, this design is misguided, since we usually want a set default view, changed only sometimes for particular questions.)